# Not able to connect to MongoDB with Auth - FIWARE Cygnus

Tags: fiware-cygnus

We have been trying today to put a Cygnus container in production and we haven't been able to connect it to MongoDB. In our case, we have installed MongoDB with the Auth flag, and we created different users in order to test everything work.

However, we didn't find out the way to connect Cygnus. It tries to connect to the `sth_default` database, but the it requires enough privileges to create other databases.

The workaround was to start the MongoDB service without the **Auth** flag, allowing us to check that everything worked when the user can access with admin user without login in, which is not the way we would like to work, due to the fact that it is insecure.

Are we missing anything?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I'm adding here the Cygnus agent.conf file. Moreover, I'm using the Docker Image (docker-ngsi: https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/cygnus-ngsi/) in its latest version.

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
# Using both, Mongo and Postgres sinks
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = mongo-sink postgresql-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = mongo-channel postgresql-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel postgresql-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMongoSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_encoding = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_grouping = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_lowercase = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.attr_persistence = row
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = MyIP:MyPort
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username = MyUsername
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password = MyPassword
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = sth_
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_size = 1
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_timeout = 30
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_ttl = 10
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_expiration = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collections_size = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.max_documents = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.ignore_white_spaces = true
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add your agent configuration? Which version of Cygnus did you installed, and how (RPM package/yum, sources, VM image)? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @frb, just updated the case with the agent configuration and the information about the Cygnus version used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration lines are missing:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMongoSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
```

I.e. you have to specify the Java class implementing the MongoDB sink, and the channel that connects the source with such a sink.

If the configuration you are showing is the default one when Cygnus is installed through Docker, then the development team must be warned.

Comment: Sorry @frb, I have other connections included in the agent.conf file and I didn't want to copy the whole file because it was huge. Those two lines are in the file, I just edited and added them (without those lines it wouldn't even connect to the MongoDB without authentication).